# Pandas library does not work in localhost

Tags: php, python, pandas, localhost

I am trying to run a Python script using PHP. my PHP file sends a parameter "hi" and my Python code prints the received parameter. Both of these files are in the localhost.

**This is my Python code:**

```
import sys
import numpy as np
print (sys.argv[1])
```

**This is my PHP code:**

```
<?php echo shell_exec("python shaden.py 'hi'");?>
```

This code runs perfectly. However, if I import pandas in my Python code it stops working and nothing is printed.

Comment: can you check and tell few things, installed pandas version and the import statement that you're writing in your python file ?

Comment: @JuhilSomaiya Thank you very much for your prompt reply. the import statement is: import pandas as pd . However, what do you mean by "installed pandas version" ?

Comment: I just wanted to check whether the pandas is correctly installed on your local machine or not ?

Comment: @JuhilSomaiya after running this statement: "pd.__version__" i found out it is: 0.23.4

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pip install pandas
```

This will install pandas on the system. If pandas is not installed, you can't import it.

If you think this is not an issue, you can put the `import` statement in a `try` block:

```
try:
    import pandas
except Exception as e:
    print(e.__repr__())
```

Another thing you could do is check the error logs. The location of logs depends on your server installation. Are you running xampp?